# How to initialize a variable in windows command shell and echo it

Tags: windows, cmd, windows-shell

How to initialize a variable in windows command shell?
I tried

```
(
var $a=1
echo $a
)
```

and got an error

```
'var' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can declare a variable in this way:

```
set MYVAR="value"
```

and echo it simply writing:

```
%MYVAR%
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the kind reply, but I want to use it for 'for' loops using a batch file, is it possible to declare variables. thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, I've a doubt in this ...Doesn't 'set' means declaring an environmental variable? thanks in advance :)

Comment: @ThalapathyaSeendunaDeadbody no. It means declaring a script variable.

Comment: Hi.One more doubt.Does it get deleted when I close the Windows Shell Command?

Comment: @ThalapathyaSeendunaDeadbody Being a script variable, yes

Comment: Do the non script variables mean path variable and environmental variables? so whatever name we declare other than environmental variables become script variables and deleted when Windows shell command is closed?

Comment: @ThalapathyaSeendunaDeadbody Environment variables can be set from the command line (or batch script) using setx. These will exist after the script has executed.

Comment: changing existing **Environmenal variables** by mistake will affect System startup?

Comment: changing Environmental variables **may** affect the system - so be sure that you know, what you do. If you choose a name for a new variable, be sure, it doesn't exist (`set <name>` will show you)

Answer (score 1):

I usually wrap the variable in percent signs...

`set blah="hello"

echo %blah%`

Answer (score 1):

To protect against most poison characters, without including double quotes in the value itself, you can use the following (and then include the double quotes to echo or manipulate it later).

```
set "variable=123 & abc"
echo "%variable%"
```

Inside a loop you most often need to use delayed expansion, and `!variable!` syntax to use the variable, like so:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%a in (1 2 3 a b c) do (
set "variable=%%a"
echo "!variable!"
)
```

Be aware that `!` characters become a poison character when using delayed expansion.

Comment: **poison characters** means those which affects system properties?

Comment: It means characters that cannot be echoed without generating an error message/issue, or those that cause the value to change from what it should be.  Examples are `<` `>` `|` `%` `^` `!` and `space` at various times.

Answer (score 0):

```
set variable=12

echo %variable%
```

Comment: I think there must not be any spaces in the `set` statement.

Comment: @plalx, i don't see any difference

Comment: @user1502952 The difference is that it won't work. While in programming languages spaces don't matter, here it does.

Comment: The spaces are included in the variable name and value - removed to make it clear.

Comment: @plalx, Ok this worked with single character say set variable = 1 but not with a string type "12", any reasons?